# Number of codes with $5$ distinct characters using $5$ letters and $9$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The letters; $A, B, C, D, E$ and the number; $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ are to be used to form codes with five distinct characters. Each code has at least one letter and has at least one number. How many codes can we form?

***My attempt:***

Choosing exactly one letter:
$^{5}P_{1} \times ^{9}P_{4}= 5 \times 3024 = 15120$ ways.

Choosing exactly two letters:
$^{5}P_{2} \times ^{9}P_{3}= 20 \times 504 = 10080$ ways.

Choosing exactly three letters:
$^{5}P_{3} \times ^{9}P_{2}= 60 \times 72 = 7320$ ways.

Choosing exactly four letters:
$^{5}P_{4} \times ^{9}P_{1}= 120 \times 9 = 1080$ ways.

So, we have a total of $15120+10080+7320+1080=33600$ different codes.

---

Please tell me if that is right or wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It is not correct, will you rethink it  ? *Hint*: You must first **choose** numeral(s) and alphabet(s) and then permute.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to think of all the codes you don't want and subtract these from the total number of codes built with all the 14 characters. The ones you don't want are those which are all numbers or are all letters.

This is just
$14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 - (9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 + 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to make the following simple modifications

Choosing exactly one letter:
$^{5}C_{1} \times ^{9}C_{4} \times 5! = $

Choosing exactly two letters:
$^{5}C_{2} \times ^{9}C_{3} \times 5! = $

Choosing exactly three letters:
$^{5}C_{3} \times ^{9}C_{2} \times 5! = $

Choosing exactly four letters:
$^{5}C_{4} \times ^{9}C_{1} \times 5! = $

Compute and add up.